# How to find and odd number $n$ s.t. $nV\subset W$?

Tags: general-topology, ideals, proof-explanation, topological-vector-spaces, vector-lattices

[Theorem 3.6 i) here](http://www.doiserbia.nb.rs/img/doi/0354-5180/2013/0354-51801301089D.pdf) (Pratulananda Das and Ekrem Savas: *On $I$-convergence of nets in locally solid Riesz spaces*, Filomat 27:1 (2013), 89–94, [DOI:10.2298/FIL1301089D](http://dx.doi.org/10.2298/FIL1301089D))

$3.6$ i) $I_τ-\lim s_α = x_0 ⇒ I_τ-\lim a.s_α = a.x_0$ for each $a ∈ \mathbb R$

**proof:** Let $U$ be a $τ$-neighborhood of zero. Choose $V ∈ N_{sol}$ such that $V ⊂ U$. Since $I-\lim s_α = x_0$,
$\{α ∈ D : s_α − x_0 ∈ V\} ∈ F(I)$.
Let $|a| ≤ 1$. Since $V$ is balanced, $s_α − x_0 ∈ V$ implies that $a (s_α − x_0) ∈ V$.
Hence we have
$$\{α ∈ D : s_α − x_0 ∈ V\} ⊂ \{α ∈ D : a.s_α − a.x_0 ∈ V\} ⊂ \{α ∈ D : a.s_α − a.x_0 ∈ U\}$$

and so
$$\{α ∈ D : a.s_α − a.x_0 ∈ U\} ∈ F (I).$$

Now let $|a| > 1$ and as usual let $[|a|]$ be the smallest integer greater than or equal to $|a|$. There exists a $\color{blue}{W ∈ N_{sol} \text{
 such that [|a|] W ⊂ V}}$. Since $I_τ-\lim s_α = x_0$,
$$A = \{α ∈ D : s_α − x_0 ∈ W\} ∈ F (I)$$ .
Then we have
$$|a.x_0 − a.s_α| = |a| |x_0 − s_α| ≤ [|a|] |x_0 − s_α| ∈ [|a|] W ⊂ V ⊂ U$$
for each $α ∈ A$. Since the set $V$ is solid, we have $a.s_α − a.x_0 ∈ V$ and so $a.s_α − a.x_0 ∈ U$ for each $α ∈ A$. So we get
$$\{α ∈ D : a.s_α − a.x_0 ∈ U\} ⊃ A$$
and so it belongs to $F(I)$. Hence $I_τ-\lim a.s_α = a.x_0$ for every $a ∈ \mathbb R$

Now the $\color{blue}{ coloured}$ part , how do we find that $W$? From the definition of $N_{sol}$ we can say we have $V_1$ s.t $V_1+V_1\subset W$ and then $V_2\in N_{sol}$ s.t. $V_2+V_2\subset V_1$ and thus $$V_2+V_2+V_2+V_2\subset W$$ and so on. going this way we can, at one stage, find that $nV\subset W$ where $n$ is even number. What happens if $|[a]|$ is odd?

Hope I could make my problem clear to you. pls help.thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know  that for each $k$ there exists $V$ such that 
$$2^k V \subseteq W.$$
(This can be done in the way you described.)

Now you can simply take $k$ large enough to have $n\le 2^k$ and you get
$$n V \subseteq 2^k V \subseteq W.$$
(Just notice that if $V\ni 0$ and $s\le t$ are positive integers, then $sV\subseteq tV$. If we apply this for $s=n$ and $t=2^k$, we get the above inclusion.)<sup>1</sup>

---

However, this is used to prove that $\newcommand{\Ilim}{\operatorname{I-lim}}\Ilim s_\alpha =x_0$ implies $\Ilim as_\alpha=ax_0$. And the proof given in the paper seems to be unnecessary complicated.

We know that $f \colon x\mapsto ax$ is a continuous function. (This is true for arbitrary [topological vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space).)

So for any convergent net and any ideal we have
$$s_\alpha \to x_0 \qquad \implies \qquad f(s_\alpha) \to f(x_0),$$
i.e.,
$$as_\alpha \to ax_0 \qquad \implies \qquad as_\alpha \to ax_0.$$

Similarly, to see that Theorem 3.6(ii) holds, we can just use continuity of addition as the map $V\times V\to V$, and the claim immediately follows. (Basically, I am just saying that we do not need to reprove from scratch facts which are already known, or things which can be easily derived from some well-known facts.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Since (based on the comments) this part seemed unclear: If $x\in sV$, this means that $x=v_1+\dots v_s$ for some $v_1,\dots,v_2\in V$. And we can now rewrite $x$ as 
$$x=v_1+\dots v_s+\underset{\text{$(t-s)$-times}}{\underbrace{0+\dots+0}}$$
to see that $x$ also belongs to $tV$.

Comment: Thank you. Actually after posting the question this occurred to me :  $V$ and $V\times \{0\}$  are homeomorphic and $V\times \{0\} \subset V\times V$ imply that $V\subset V\times \{0\}$.

Comment: $V\subset V\times\{0\}$ is certainly not true. The latter is a set of ordered pairs.

Comment: Sorry sorry. I meant $V\subset V\times V.$

Comment: That has still the same problem. (And it is not true in general.)

Comment: then how can we say $nV\subseteq 2^kV$  for $n\le 2^k\ ?$

Comment: In general, if $a\le b$ (where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers) you have $aV\subseteq bV$ for any neighborhood of zero. (See the edit.)

Comment: OK. So if I take the nbd $V=(-1,1)$ of $0$ in $\mathbb R$, I get $V+V=(-2,2)$. But if it is any open set say $V=(1,2)$ that does not hold,right? In this paper only nbd's of $\theta$ have been relevant i.e. the base at $0.$ But if using translation, I shift the base at some $x_0\neq 0$ then what happens to this relation? If you say that requires detailed disscussion then I'm happy to make a different post on this question.

Comment: You are right. If $0\in V$ and $V$ is subset of a topological vector space, then we have $aV\subseteq bV$ for $a\le b$. (In your example, $V\subseteq V+V$, i.e., $a=1$ and $b=2$.) But the same is not true if $V$ is an arbitrary subset. (The fact that $0\in V$ is important here.) I have tried to clarify this a bit in my last edit.